# Jssor List Slider - Add Arrows

Tags: slider, jssor, arrows

I am unsuccessfully trying to add arrows above and below the thumbnail & text list controls on the right side.

There is not an example for this in the full pack.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html

Please leave me a comment if there is still problem.